# How to route tcp traffic from all/range of ports to a single port?

Tags: windows, proxy, iptables, netsh

I would like to do something that's possible with IPTABLES(for linux), on a Windows 10 - that is to route multiple ports to a single port.

I thought I'd manage to do it with `netsh`, but it doesn't state such a possibility in the documentation. example of what I've tried (**not possible**):

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=1-65000 connectaddress=X connectport=8080”
```

I guess I could write an automation to go port by port, but that seems really hackish.

What native windows feature or tool can I use to accomplish this goal?

Comment: Why not with port forwarding?

Comment: What do you suggest?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/440324/iptables-how-to-forward-all-external-ports-to-one-local-port

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you wish to do it, and you re missing the `connectaddress`
parameter, but it can be run 65000 times via a loop.

In the Command Prompt (cmd):

```
FOR /L %G IN (1,1,65000) DO netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=%G connectaddress=X connectport=8080
```

In a `.bat` file:

```
FOR /L %%G IN (1,1,65000) DO netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=%%G connectaddress=X connectport=8080
```